# Python: shuffle array of strings including duplicates while maintaining distribution of items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have an array of strings that can include duplicated entries. I need to randomly re-assign each unique string to all locations of another randomly selected string in the array, bearing in mind that a string with multiple original locations could be mapped to one new location, and vice versa. Effectively, I'm re-assigning keys in the array, but keeping the original distribution of keys.

I have a working Pandas & numpy implementation that works for mixed input types, but it is inefficient at scale as it loops over every unique value (I will need this to work effectively for 1m+ values minimum, ideally more). The slow bit here is the enumeration itself:

```
def shuffle_fields(series):
    # Create a copy of the original series.
    _series = series.copy()

    # Get non-NaN keys of original data.
    keys = series[pd.notnull(_series)].unique()

    # Create a copy of these keys.
    _keys = np.copy(keys)

    # Shuffle the copy.
    np.random.shuffle(_keys)

    # Iterate over all zipped keys and set values in copy of series.
    for i, (val, new) in enumerate(zip(keys, _keys)):

        # Need to key off series as _series is being changed during the loop.
        _series.loc[series == val] = new

    return _series
```

Example input:

```
_input = pd.Series(['One', 'One', np.NaN, 2, np.NaN, True, 2, 2, 'One', 'One'])
```

Expected output:

```
output = pd.Series([2, 2, np.NaN, True, np.NaN, 'One', True, True, 2, 2])
```

Open to suggestions on any implementation that will work at scale. I'm not beholden to something that will work with mixed data types (as with the example above), but it's a nice bonus. The technique must be able to handle null/NaN values, i.e. NaN values should remain unchanged.

Comment: How does four `'One`'s from the input only result in one `One` and one `True` become three? It's probably me missing something but ummm?

Comment: Aye, it's part of the requirements. Essentially i need to crate a dictionary mapping for each key to map to another key. In this example the `'One'` key maps to `2`, `2` maps to `True`, and `True` maps to `'One'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works assuming that you can compare for equality based on the string representation of the objects:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
_input = pd.Series(['One', 'One', np.NaN, 2, np.NaN, True, 2, 2, 'One', 'One'])
v = _input.values
uniq, idx = np.unique(v.astype(str), return_inverse=True)
r = np.random.permutation(len(uniq))
output = pd.Series(uniq[r[idx]])
print(output)
# 0     nan
# 1     nan
# 2       2
# 3    True
# 4       2
# 5     One
# 6    True
# 7    True
# 8     nan
# 9     nan
# dtype: object
```

Comment: I should have specified that nan elements should remain in place, but that can be handled easily enough by removing them first and then adding them back in. Will try this solution to see how it does at scale...

Comment: Just to update, the above solution can handle 1M unique values in ~1 second. Exactly what I was looking for!